# "How to open scaffold drawer from the custom AppBar ?"

Tags: flutter, dart

I have made customized `Drawer` and `AppBar`. I want the `Drawer` to be opened when action widget in the `AppBar` is tapped. I want to know how to implement this for the custom `AppBar`

```dart
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   endDrawer:buildProfileDrawer(),
   appBar: setAppBar(),
   body: HomeBody()
  );
}

//custom widget
Widget setAppBar(){
  return AppBar(
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle,),
        onPressed: () {
          //Open the drawer
        },
      )
    ],
  );
}

//Custom drawer
buildProfileDrawer() {
  return Drawer(
    //....drawer childs
  );    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `GlobalKey` in `Scaffold`, and call `openEndDrawer` method on it.

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey(); // add this

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    key: _key, // set it here
    endDrawer: buildProfileDrawer(),
    appBar: setAppBar(),
    body: Center(),
  );
}

//custom widget
Widget setAppBar() {
  return AppBar(
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
        onPressed: () {
          _key.currentState.openEndDrawer(); // this opens drawer
        },
      )
    ],
  );
}

//Custom drawer
buildProfileDrawer() {
  return Drawer();
}
```

---

**Update**

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _key,
      endDrawer: buildProfileDrawer(),
      appBar: setAppBar(_key),
      body: Center(),
    );
  }
```

Somewhere in some file.

```
Widget setAppBar(GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> globalKey) {
  return AppBar(
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
        onPressed: () {
          globalKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
        },
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

Somewhere in some other file

```
buildProfileDrawer() {
  return Drawer();
}
```

Comment: If these three widgets are in separate files then what should be the approach? I get error when I pass `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key ` argument inside the AppBar()

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this in actions list:**

```
 StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, setState) {
              return IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.format_align_right),
                onPressed: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
                },
              );
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use

`Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();`

on onPressed inside an IconButton in your CustomAppBar or wherever you want to call the drawer.

In the Scaffold just ensure to provide the `drawer:` property a Drawer Widget.

Comment: This approach results in an error: FlutterError Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.  It is thrown because the context of the AppBar doesn't contain the scaffold.